# Neo4j best way to model a timeline

Tags: datetime, graph, neo4j

There is a blog post https://neo4j.com/blog/modeling-a-multilevel-index-in-neoj4/ which states

> The basic problem we try to solve here is the ordering of events in a timeline and asking for ranges of events ordered in time without needing to load the whole timeline, or let an external index like Lucene doing the sorting (which is very costly).

The technique was in 2012 a good way to construct a timeline that is still performant. Since then (i don't know when exactly) temporal values and indexes on these values have been introduced. See https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/

Is there still any benefit of constructing a graph like in the blog post or is just using temporal values the way to go now?

Any additional information on versioning nodes (on a timeline) and putting events (on a timeline) is also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the new temporal types can be [indexed, and also support range lookups](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/), the multi-level index approach is now obsolete.

For example, assuming that `Event` nodes have a `date` property with a [date](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/date/) value, and that there is an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/#administration-indexes-search-performance) on `:Event(date)`, you can now simply do this to efficiently get (in ascending date order) all `Event`s between 2011-01-01 and 2011-01-03, inclusive:

```
MATCH (e:Event)
WHERE date({month:1,day:1,year:2011}) <= e.date <= date({month:1,day:3,year:2011})
RETURN e ORDER BY e.date
```